# Return value of wait() in C program

Tags: c

I am trying to print current value of wait() function. What I conceive from output is that when child process is running then current value of wait() in child context is -1 and once it is completed and returned then in parent context wait() has value equals to it's child's pid. Is this implication is correct from what I understand?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()

{
 int statloc;
int stat;
 printf("\nthis process id is %d", getpid());

 int pid;
pid =fork();
stat=wait(&statloc);

printf("\n Value of stat is %d",stat);
getchar();
}
```

**Output :**

```
       this process id is 10740
 Value of stat is -1k                 // k is entered as input due to getchar
        this process id is 10740
 Value of stat is 10741j               // j is entered as input due to getchar
```

Comment: Only the parent should wait. Also note that it's UB to call async-unsafe functions after `fork()` returns in the child.

Comment: man wait: "wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned. "

Comment: @KerrekSB :  Ok yes , silly me , I understand wait() value twice is of parent's . So my question is wait is -1 until child exits and after that has value that of exited child's pid ?

Comment: No, wait returns -1 on error and blocks otherwise until a child exits (or returns immediately if that already happened). The manpage wait(2) is a good source of information regarding this.

Comment: @Ctx : I think blocking and error means the same thing here

Comment: @theartist33 This is not the case. Blocking: waiting for an event (i.e. a child exiting). Error: something is wrong (i.e. no child to wait for)

Comment: @Ctx:  I know generalised blocking and error, but here in this situation after generating fork and wait , parent is waiting for child to complete , and child is still running because there is getchar() which has blocked child for input. till I hit 'k' button which means wait() value as -1 doesn't mean that there is no child .

Comment: @theartist33 You are confused: The parent calls `wait()` and blocks, waiting for the child to terminate. Then, the child calls `wait()`, which returns error -1 (ECHILD), since it has no child process to wait for, which you print. Finally, when you enter `k`, the child process terminates and the `wait()` in the parent returns with the child's pid. The parent prints it and waits for a char, then terminates, too. Everything clear now?

Comment: @Ctx: Yes I think this logic is correct. I do'nt know why I am so good in creating problems for myself many a times. ;)

Comment: One more thing , can you tell me why getpid() value is same in both child and parent's context ? I know this is correct but I could have typically expected getpid() throwing child's pid when running in child's context.

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/wait.html

Comment: @theartist33 *One more thing , can you tell me why getpid() value is same in both child and parent's context?*  It's not.  `getpid()` is only called once, in the parent process.  What you're seeing is almost certainly the common `stdout` buffer between the parent and the child process getting flushed after the `fork()` call.  `fork()` duplicates the *entire* memory space of the process - including any data that hasn't been flushed out to any files or streams. Add a `fflush( stdout )` before `fork()` and the doubling of the PID `printf()` output should disappear.

Comment: Great @AndrewHenle !

Comment: @Kerrek SB  Your first comment confuses me... Does that mean you can't `exec()` a program using unsafe sync functions?

Comment: @jdarthenay: `exec` is async-safe. Basically, the only things you're allowed to do after `fork()` are either `exit` or `exec`...

Comment: @Kerrec I don't understand. `exec()` loads another program, executing it instead of current program. So if forked process should use only async-safe function, I don't see why the program who takes its place would not have to obey the same constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I think Your understanding is wrong.

The use of wait is it waits until any one of the child process is to exit.
If the child process exits, it returns the process id of the exited child process and it store the exit status of the process in the passed argument for the wait function.

We can get the exit status using the WEXITSTATUS() macro.

In that macro we have to pass the argument passed to the wait system call. If we pass that it returns the real exit status of the process.

To know more about the wait read the below link.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html

Comment: I know this, what I was confused about that wait() is -1 because child is still running and once child terminates wait() corresponds to child's pid which is not the case as been cleared up by @ Ctx above in comment

Comment: And one thing, If we didn't pass any argument to the wait(), if the process is exited, that time also it returns -1. Not the process id of the exited child.

Comment: on my machine it doesnt compile even , throws error: too few arguments to function 'wait'

Comment: on my machine it doesnt compile even , throws error: too few arguments to function 'wait'